# Sorting and adding new gallery - images loaded from Flickr

Tags: jquery, api, sorting, addition, flickr

I make a simple gallery with Flickr api:

html:

```
<div id="html"><h4>Tag: html</h4></div>
```

js:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "html",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).attr("data-published", item.published).attr("data-taken", item.date_taken).appendTo("#html").wrap("<a href='" + item.link + "'></a>");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

It display 4 photos with specify tag. Now I want to make sort option. Sorting should display 4 photos ordered by published or taken date (attributes are data-published and data-taken). It should use data collected during loading gallery.
I tray to make it like on this website: http://mixitup.io/demos/template
but it don't work for me.

Second option is possibility to create and remove galleries- input to enter new gallery (gallery name = tag) and list of existing galleries with link to remove.

Answer (score 0):

take a look @ http://mixitup.io/#Methods >>> sort by custom array

```
Syntax: $('#Grid').mixitup('sort',['custom',array]);
```

This method animates the elements to a new custom order (not necessarily sorted by a particular attribute). The new order should be an array of the target elements, with each element as a jQuery object, in the desired order.

Comment: don't work. images are loaded dynamically and that can be a problem.